# how to Include videos in AIR captive runtime(ADT command line)

Tags: flash, air

I have already successfully use this AIR captive runtime for embedding AIR in to the application. but my problem is that the embedded videos on my app is not included because it is not on the xml how. my question is how can i include these flash videos to my android app?

Answer (score 0):

You add `files_and_dirs yourDir` to the command -> [File and path options - ADT](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128fc240122-7ff2.html)

Comment: "adt -package -target apk-captive-runtime - storetype pkcs12 -keystore HitTheBeatp12 -storepass 12345 HitTheaBeat.apk HitTheBeat-app.xml HitTheaBeat.swf image.png"

                                       (this is my command line for captive runtime. now how can i add a .flv or .f4v file?)

Comment: its all in the link. but if your video is in the main directory then just: adt -package -target apk-captive-runtime - storetype pkcs12 -keystore HitTheBeatp12 -storepass 12345 HitTheaBeat.apk HitTheBeat-app.xml HitTheaBeat.swf image.png myvid.flv